# Autolayouting : constraint for the same height and width

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've following constraint with visual format

`@"|-(0)-[[view0]-(5)-[view1(view0)]-(5)-[view2(view0)]-(5)-[view3(view0)]-(0)-|"`

The number of the views is big, for simplicity lets consider only 3 views

With above constraint I set the view to have the same width. 
But also need to set for the views to have the same height !

Is there a way to specify in above constraint for both width AND height of the views to be the same ?

I know that it is possible to set the constraint for the view to have the same height like this 
`@"V:[view1(view0)]` and `@"V:[view2(view0)]`, but I would like to have only one visual constraint string.

Any suggestions/references are welcomed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is *no*, you can't mix height and width in the same visual layout string. I will explain why below.

First, here is a link to the [Auto Layout Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html). This defines what is a valid string for `-[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:]`.

From that reference page, we see that a valid visual format string is defined as:

```
(<orientation>:)?
(<superview><connection>)?
<view>(<connection><view>)*
(<connection><superview>)?
```

Orientation is what we're interested in. From the above definition, we can set orientation at the beginning of a visual format string. Are there any other places we can set orientation? No. drilling down into the other symbols (`<superview>`, `<connection>`, and `<view>`), the symbol `<orientation>` does not appear again.

Let's look at the symbol `<orientation>` now. It is defined as:

```
H|V
```

meaning you can replace `<orientation>` with either `H` (horizontal) or `V` (vertical).

That means that

```
(<orientation>:)?
```

is either `(H:)?` or `(V:)?`

The `?` character means you can either have 0 or 1 of what is contained in parentheses. This gives us three possibilities for `(<orientation>:)?`: `H:`, `V:`, or nothing (which is equivalent to `H:`).

As shown, there is only one place to set orientation in a visual format string, and it can be set to either horizontal *or* vertical, not both. That means you can only set height *or* width in a single visual format string.

Comment: That last section about sidestepping the problem is wrong. It will arrange the views vertically, with the specified spacing, but that's not what he wants. He just wants them to have the same height.